# What is the cohomology of the tangent bundle of a flag variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be the general linear group $\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $P$ a parabolic subgroup with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{p}$. Consider the vector bundles 
$$
  \mathcal{P} = G\times_P \mathfrak{p} \subset G/P \times \mathfrak{gl}
$$
and
$$
  \mathcal{T}_{G/P} = G\times_P \mathfrak{g/p}.
$$

I would like to understand the space of sections of the latter, eventually in a way which works if $G$ is any principal bundle.

Bott showed that there is an exact sequence
$$
0\rightarrow H^0(G/P,\mathcal{P}) \rightarrow H^0(G/P,\mathcal{O}_{G/P}\otimes\mathfrak{g})\rightarrow H^0(G/P,\mathcal{P})\rightarrow H^1(G/P,\mathcal{P})\rightarrow 0
$$

Question 1: If $G/P = \mathbb{P}^{1}$ then $H^0(\mathbb{P}^{1}, \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^{1}}) = \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{C}^{2})/\mathbb{C} I$. How does $\mathcal{P}$ split as a direct sum of line bundles on $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Question 2: Is there a vanishing theorem for $H^1(G/P,\mathcal{P})$ for other flag varieties?

Related question: [cohomology of tangent bundle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122415/cohomology-of-tangent-bundle)

Comment: I don't understand your first question. As for the second --- in characteristic zero you can use Borel--Bott--Weil to answer it.

Comment: Concerning the first question, the answer is $O \oplus O(-1) \oplus O(-1)$.

Comment: @sasha : since the global sections are 3-dim, there must be a misprint in your comment.

Comment: BS. He is talking about the sheaf $\mathfrak{p}$, which you would expect to be rank 3, degree -2 and have vanishing cohomology in this case.

Comment: oops! I misread the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer might be in

Michel Demazure. Automorphismes et déformations des variétés de Borel. Invent. Math., 39(2):179–186, 1977

Comment: Fantastic, thank you Giulio! I don't think I would've found that paper on my own. There is a very nice exposition of the results of Demazure and Bott in the book Dmitri N. Akhiezer, Aspects of Mathematics, vol. E27, Friedr. Vieweg, Braunschweig and Wiesbaden, 1995.

I picked up this reference from http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160292/automorphism-group-of-flag-manifolds